# react add event listener base on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add attach event to jsx's element base on condition? The below example didn't do that, it simply pass a flag into the onClick function, didn't really attach the event.

```
const { hasSomething, name } = this.props 

render(){
   return(
     <div onClick={()=>{hasSomething && this.fireSomething()}}>{name}/div> 
   )
}
```

I can duplicate 2 `<div>`, check if `hasSomething` exist then attach it to one of the element, but that's a bad duplication for me as {name} is declared twice.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your logic. Per say, you can also prepare props (based on different conditions) and pass the props variable/object with spread `...` operator in your render tag in `render()`. e.g. `<div {...myPrepared_conditionalProps} ></div>`

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
render(){
   return(
      <div onClick={hasSomething && this.fireSomething}>{name}/div> 
   )
}
```

If `hasSomething` attach listener otherwise `onClick` will receive **undefined** just as you would not pass anything.

If above isn't something you are looking for you can also do something like this:

```
render(){
   const props = {
     //... some props
   }

   if(hasSomething) {
     props.onClick = this.fireSomething;
   }

   return(
      <div {...props}>{name}/div> 
   )
}
```

You create an object that holds every prop that should be passed to div and later you use spread operator to pass them.

Comment: you still have onClick attached.

Comment: @JennyMok I've included another example to the answer. Maybe that's more of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to bind the function to `this`, if you need to reference props/state.  I tend to do it in the construction i.e.
`this.fireSomething = this.fireSomething.bind(this)`

Comment: no, I used arrow function, there's no need for bind like you says.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is creating a new props object `newProps` that might or might not have an `onClick` property according to whether `this.props` has the required property.

In this example, if `Foo` does not received a `bar` prop, it won't create a new object with an `onClick` property.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  handleBar() {
    console.log(this.props.bar);
  }

  render() {
    const newProps = this.props.bar
      ? {
        ...this.props,
        onClick: this.handleBar.bind(this),
      }
      : this.props
    return <div { ...newProps }/>
  }
}
```

Here's a [live example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/jesseminn/pen/jYygwQ?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you just want to call a method if a condition is met? In that case you can just do this:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div onClick={() => {
      if (hasSomething) {
        this.fireSomething()
      }
    }}
  )
}
```

or

```
fireSomething() {
  if (hasSomething) {
    // do logic
  }
}

render() {
  return(
    <div onClick={() => this.fireSomething()}
  )
}
```